# Ctrl click style multiselecting with the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gui

Is there a way (in modern browsers) to multi-select items from a list with the keyboard? I'm looking for the equivalent of ctrl clicking without using a mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press the CTLR button, hold it. Then move with the arrow to the other item, hit SPACE. Then repeat that!

Comment: Yeah, Space bar works like a Mouse click.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but it was an obscure webapp and not a standard windows/linux app.